# how to align 4 imageview in single row eqaul weight?

Tags: android

i want to show 4 imageview in single row with eqaul witdth with textview but my screen look like this see this:

[image]

Attech both screen mys creen with sample scren tell me how do i do that?

```
  <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCCCCC"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a width of 0, and weight of 1 on all elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCCCCC"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```